# Python Regex to start from inner match

Tags: python, regex, sympy

I am working on a regex in Python that is converting a mathematical expression to the power format in Sympy language **pow(x,y)**. For example, it takes `2^3` and returns `pow(2,3)`.

My current pattern is:

```
# pattern
pattern = re.compile(r'(.+?)\^(.*)')
```

To find the math for nested expressions, I use a for loop to count the number of ^(hat)s and then use re.sub to generate the power format:

```
# length of the for loop
num_hat = len(re.findall(r'\^', exp))

# for nested pow
for i in range(num_hat): 
   exp = re.sub(pattern, r'pow(\1,\2)', exp)
return exp
```

This method does not work for nested ^ expressions such as `a^b^c^d` or `sin(x^2)^3` as the position of the final parenthesis is not correct.

For `a^b^c^d` it returns `pow(pow(pow(a,b,c,d)))`

For `sin(x^2)^3` it returns `pow(pow(sin(x,2),3))`

Is there any way to overcome this issue? I tried the negative lookahead but it is still not working

Comment: I think this cannot be solved by regex alone as the possibilities of combinations are infinite. Maybe you could find a math parser somewhere. But one algorithm that might be useful to you is called "Shunting-Yard Algorithm"

Comment: Have you considered simply replacing all the `^` characters in your expression with `**`?

Comment: A regex is the wrong tool for this problem unless the expressions being matched are a very tiny, restricted, subset of possible mathematical expressions.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon yes, but since the result of this part is going to be used in other parts that are working with pow format, I have to stick with this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no nice way of saying this, but you have an extreme case of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What you apparently want is to convert some mathematical expression to SymPy. Writing your own regular expression seems like a very tedious, error-prone, and possibly impossible approach to this.

Being a vast symbolic library, SymPy comes with an entire [parsing submodule](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html), which allows you to tweak the parsing expressions in all detail, in particular `convert_xor` governs what happens to the `^` character. However, it appears you do not need to do anything since converting `^` to exponentiation is the default. You can therefore simply do:

```py
from sympy import sympify
print( sympy.sympify("a^b^c^d") )    # a**(b**(c**d))
print( sympy.sympify("sin(x^2)^3") ) # sin(x**2)**3
```

Note that `**` is equivalent to `pow`, so I am not sure why you are insisting on the latter. If you need an output that shall work in yet another programming language, that’s what the [printing module](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html) is for and it’s comparably easy to change this yourself. Another thing that may help you obtain the desired form is `sympy.srepr`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Yes, I agree this requires a more robust method, as @chthonicdaemon suggested about replacing `^` with `**`, I think this solution will be the correct answer. I also found `sympy.srepr` extremely helpful in performing advanced manipulation of expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use recursion for this? It might not be the best, but will work for your use case if the nested powers are not a lot,

A small demonstration,

```
import re

#Your approach
def func(exp):
    # pattern
    pattern = re.compile(r'(.+?)\^(.*)')
    
    # length of the for loop
    num_hat = len(re.findall(r'\^', exp))
    
    # for nested pow
    for i in range(num_hat):  # num_hat-1 since we created the first match already
       exp = re.sub(pattern, r'pow(\1,\2)', exp)
    return exp
    
#With recursion
def refined_func(exp):
    # pattern
    pattern = '(.+?)\^(.*)'
    
    # length of the for loop
    num_hat = len(re.findall(r'\^', exp))
    
    #base condition
    if num_hat == 1:
        search = re.search(pattern, exp)
        group1 = search.group(1)
        group2 = search.group(2)
        
        exp = "pow("+group1+", "+group2+")"
        return exp
    
    # for nested pow
    for i in range(num_hat):  # num_hat-1 since we created the first match already
       search = re.search(pattern, exp)
       if not search: # the point where there are no hats in the exp
           break
       group1 = search.group(1)
       group2 = search.group(2)
       
       exp = "pow("+group1+", "+refined_func(group2)+")"
       
    return exp

if __name__=='__main__':
    
    print(func("a^b^c^d"))
    
    print("###############")
    
    print(refined_func("a^b^c^d"))
```

The output of the above program is,

```
pow(pow(pow(a,b,c,d)))                                                                                                                
###############                                                                                                                       
pow(a, pow(b, pow(c, d)))
```

Problem in your approach:

Initially you start off with the following expression,

```
a^b^c^d
```

With your defined regex, two parts are made of the above expression -> part1: `a` and part2: `b^c^d`. With these two, you generate `pow(a,b^c^d)`. So the next expression that you work with is,

```
pow(a,b^c^d)
```

In this case now, your regex will give part1 to be `pow(a,b` and part2 will be `c^d)`. Since, the pow statement used to construct the info from part1 and part2 is like `pow(part1, part2)`, you end up having `pow( pow(a,b , c^d) )` which is not what you intended.

Comment: I tried the idea of recursion. Since we can have multiple powers, it sounds like the possible method of handling this. However, some of the expressions might still be a problem, like sin(x^2)^3. 
Is it possible to find x^2 first and then sin(...)^3 ? (comming from the inside to the outside)

Answer (score 0):

I made an attempt into your examples but I'll still advise you to find a math parser (from my comment) as this regex is very complex.

```
import re


pattern = re.compile(r"(\w+(\(.+\))?)\^(\w+(\(.+\))?)([^^]*)$")


def convert(string):
    while "^" in string:
        string = pattern.sub(r"pow(\1, \3)\5", string, 1)
    return string

print(convert("a^b^c^d"))  # pow(a, pow(b, pow(c, d)))
print(convert("sin(x^2)^3"))  # pow(sin(pow(x, 2)), 3)
```

Explanation: Loop while there is a `^` and replace the last match (presence of `$`)

Comment: Thank you for the solution, can you explain what ([^^]*) part in the pattern will do?

Comment: If inside the square brackets (metaclass) it means character that is `not ^`. This is different when used outside and at the start of a string which indicates string should start with a specific pattern/character.